# How sqoop converts sql datatypes into hive

Tags: sql-server, hive, sqoop

I need complete list of SQL Server datatypes converted to hive in sqoop.

Like SQL Server's `timestamp` is converted to hive `string`, SQL Server `varchar` is converted to hive `string`, etc.

Where can I find this complete mapping?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For Java mapping**

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE-NAME> WHERE 1=0
```

Query is used. It will fetch no records but metadata.

Useful source [code](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/0e26d92a34029b21a2dff7c42839714913960513/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/manager/SqlManager.java#L107):

```
  protected String getColNamesQuery(String tableName) {
    // adding where clause to prevent loading a big table
    return "SELECT t.* FROM " + escapeTableName(tableName) + " AS t WHERE 1=0";
  }
```

Then it uses `ResulSetMetadata` to find datatypes.

Useful source [code](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/0e26d92a34029b21a2dff7c42839714913960513/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/manager/SqlManager.java#L148) for generic JDBC,

```
  int cols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
  ResultSetMetaData metadata = results.getMetaData();
  for (int i = 1; i < cols + 1; i++) {
    String colName = metadata.getColumnLabel(i);
    if (colName == null || colName.equals("")) {
      colName = metadata.getColumnName(i);
      if (null == colName) {
        colName = "_RESULT_" + i;
      }
    }
    columns.add(colName);
    LOG.debug("Found column " + colName);
```

Mapping from `--map-column-java` is overridden on this mapping.

---

**For Hive Mapping**

This mapping is used:

```
 public static String toHiveType(int sqlType) {

      switch (sqlType) {
          case Types.INTEGER:
          case Types.SMALLINT:
              return "INT";
          case Types.VARCHAR:
          case Types.CHAR:
          case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
          case Types.NVARCHAR:
          case Types.NCHAR:
          case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
          case Types.DATE:
          case Types.TIME:
          case Types.TIMESTAMP:
          case Types.CLOB:
              return "STRING";
          case Types.NUMERIC:
          case Types.DECIMAL:
          case Types.FLOAT:
          case Types.DOUBLE:
          case Types.REAL:
              return "DOUBLE";
          case Types.BIT:
          case Types.BOOLEAN:
              return "BOOLEAN";
          case Types.TINYINT:
              return "TINYINT";
          case Types.BIGINT:
              return "BIGINT";
          default:
        // TODO(aaron): Support BINARY, VARBINARY, LONGVARBINARY, DISTINCT,
        // BLOB, ARRAY, STRUCT, REF, JAVA_OBJECT.
        return null;
      }
  }
```

Check source code [here](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/hive/HiveTypes.java#L39).

Mapping from `--map-column-hive` is overridden on this mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop is preconfigured to map most SQL types to appropriate Java or Hive representatives. However the default mapping might not be suitable for everyone and might be overridden.

```
sqoop import ... --map-column-java id=String,value=Integer
```

See Sqoop user guide: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_type_mapping

Also some other config properties may affect type mapping, like `sqoop.bigdecimal.format.string`, etc

Probably you need to study source codes for complete list of preconfigured mappings. But specifying them as --map-column-java or --map-column-hive gives you more control. You can [generate mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45053915/2700344) from target tables metadata.

Comment: Thanks lefjoin... actually i'm looking for complete list of preconfigured mappings. I'll check in source code.