# sqoop import from postgresql to parquet / avro - timestamp epoch millis vs date type

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, sqoop

Ok, so I may have overloaded the title a little bit but we are pulling data in with sqoop 1.4.6.2.5.3.0-37 ( hdp 2.5.3 ).

When sqoop does its import timestamp fields are coming in as milliseconds epoch.

postgres schema

```
Column      |           Type           |                         Modifiers
------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
id               | integer                  | not null default nextval('foo'::regclass)
x      | integer                  |
y    | integer                  |
z | character varying(255)   |
created_at       | timestamp with time zone |
updated_at       | timestamp with time zone |
```

hive schema

```
id                      int
x           int
y           int
z       string
created_at              bigint
updated_at              bigint
```

How can I get the sqoop import to treat the timestamp fields as dates natively in parquet/avro?

The data is configured as an external table so we can hit it directly with things like java / spark. I've tried a few different field mappings ( java ) but so far nothing is actually preserving the type

Comment: add a sample record of Postgres and Hive table

Comment: Also sqoop import command

Comment: hive: 

    1477511476400 1477511476400
    1477511477926 1477511477926

postgres:

    2016-02-23 14:00:21.426484-05 | 2016-02-23 14:00:21.426484-05
    2016-02-23 14:00:25.174434-05 | 2016-02-23 14:00:25.174434-05

Same query for both: select created_at,updated_at from table limit 2;

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop creates a POJO class for this Postgres table. It's converting  `created_at` and `updated_at` into `Types.BIGINT`.

That's why you are getting its corresponding `BIGINT` datatype in Hive.

In hive, Timestamps are interpreted to be timezoneless. If you try to insert `2016-02-23 14:00:21.426484-05` in hive's timestamp value it will insert `NULL` for that.

All you can do is to convert these columns in `VARCHAR` or `STRING`

Try adding Java mapping

```
--map-column-java created_at=String, updated_at=String
```

and hive mapping

```
--map-column-hive created_at=string, updated_at=string
```

or

```
--map-column-hive created_at='varchar(50)', updated_at='varchar(50)'
```

For sqoop's default java and hive mapping check : [How sqoop converts sql datatypes into hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013954/how-sqoop-converts-sql-datatypes-into-hive/43026506#43026506)

Comment: Will that cast as an actual date or just the string version of the date per row? We still want it as a date type for querying and transport to other databases

Comment: @BillSchwanitz As I mentioned in the answer if you try inserting `2016-02-23 14:00:21.426484-05` into a hive's timestamp type, it will insert **NULL**. Hive's Date time only store only date part.  Check hive [docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types)