# what are the data types allowed with the sqoop option "--map-column-java"?

Tags: hive, sqoop

I want to use sqoop import to import data from SQL Server, however I am facing some data type conversion issues, and I want to use "--map-column-java" to solve that.

Just in case anybody wants to suggest "--map-column-hive". I can't because I am importing to "--as-parquetfile"; therefore I have to cast the columns data types before inserted in the file.

**So, what are the data types allowed with the sqoop option "--map-column-java"?**

---

P.S. 
**Especially I want to know the "datetime" data type that works with "--map-column-java"**

Comment: Hi, all the java datatypes. Be awear to put the first letter in uppercase and th rest in lowercase. Example: "--map-column-java=Integer"

Comment: This may be useful as a good start for generating map-column https://stackoverflow.com/a/45053915/2700344

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty taught to load from database into parquet through sqoop, keeping the source datatypes, from the datatypes point of view. For example, you can't load timestamp because it's not supported.

I'm suggesting you the next workaround:

1. Load with sqoop with all the datatypes string;
2. Insert from table 1 (with all the datatypes string) into table 2, using cast (as timestamp, as decimal ... etc);

Example:

```
--map-column-java "ID=String,NR_CARD=String,TIP_CARD_ID=String,CONT_CURENT_ID=String,AUTORIZ_CONTURI_ID=String,TIP_STARE_ID=String,DATA_STARE=String,COMIS=String,BUGETARI_ID=String,DATA_SOLICITARII=String,DATA_EMITERII=String,DATA_VALABILITATII=String,TIP_DESCOPERIT_ID=String,BRANCH_CODE_EMIT=String,ORG_ID=String,DATA_REGEN=String,FIRMA_ID=String,VOUCHER_BLOC=String,CANAL_CERERE=String,CODE_BUG_OPER=String,CREATED_BY=String,CREATION_DATE=String,LAST_UPDATED_BY=String,LAST_UPDATE_DATE=String,LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN=String,IDPAN=String,MOTIV_STARE_ID=String,DATA_ACTIVARII=String" \
```

In this way you will have all the datatypes, correctly loaded from source.