# Implicit data types conversion in hive

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

How to make implicit data types conversion when importing data from oracle to HIVE using Sqoop without using the manual mapping **--map-column-hive   .**
The default conversion is to convert data types to (DOUBLE OR STRING).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the SQL types to Java or Hive-specific types mappings are Sqoop native. However, default mapping might not be suitable for everyone and can be override by `--map-column-hive`, i.e. specifying them as `--map-column-java` or `--map-column-hive` gives you more control. Given a JDBC SQL types coming from another database, the best mapping to a Hive-specific type that is prebuilt in Sqoop looks like [this](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/hive/HiveTypes.java#L55-L90). If you want to generate mappings from target table metadata. You can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052340/how-to-use-sqoop-import-command-with-map-column-hive/45053915#45053915) with shell and awk.